# Javascript: Converting frequencies to percentages using reduce()?

Tags: javascript, reduce

A function in my code takes an array of numbers and puts into a map the first digits of those numbers and the amount of times they appeared in the array. So for example, for an array of

```
[1539, 1390, 1023, 2642, 3912, 7419, 7129, 9520, 2239]
```

The resulting map would be

```
{"1" => 3, "2" => 2, "3" => 1, "7" => 2, "9" => 1}
```

For the function I'm working on now, I have to take that resulting map and convert it to a map with percentages. However the catch is, I have to use **only** the reduce() and map() functions.

So far, I only know how to actually compute the physical frequencies, as I did before, but I don't know how to use reduce() to convert them all to percentages.  This is my code so far:

```
function toPercentages(benfordMap) {
    let keys = [ ...benfordMap.keys()];
    let values = [ ...benfordMap.values()];

values.reduce(
    (acc, currVal) => {
    // do something
  })

    return values;
}
```

I have a *general* idea of what to do, I feel like I can use the code I used to compute the frequencies, but I don't know how to incorporate the syntax. My frequency code looks like this:

```
function freqs(items) {
var Frequencies = new Map();
items.reduce(
    (acc, currVal) => (
        acc[currVal] = ++acc[currVal] || 1, acc
    ),
    {}
  );

for (var x in items){
    Frequencies.set(x, items[x]);
}

return Frequencies;
}
```

I'm excessively new to Javascript so I don't know exactly where in the reduce() function I would add the percentage-computing code. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You wouldn't put the percentage-computing code in the `.reduce()` callback. You'd do the `.reduce()` to accumulate the counts into an array with 10 (the ten digits), then use `.map()`  to turn that into an array with percentages, and then use `.reduce()` again to turn that into an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, that I understand right, but anyway check the code below:

```js
var obj = {"1": 3, "2": 2, "3": 1, "7": 2, "9": 1}

function toPercentages(obj){
  let m = new Map()
  const sum = Object.keys(obj).reduce( (acum, item) => {   
      return acum + obj[item];
  }, 0);
  
  Object.keys(obj).map( key => {
    m.set(key, ((obj[key]/sum) * 100).toFixed(2));    
  })
  
  return m;
}

toPercentages(obj);
```

Comment: This returns [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object] in my console, do you need anymore clarification on my question?

Comment: change array to map structure

Comment: Thanks, I used your code basically as a framework. Helped guide me in the right direction.